# No Grease Pencil Option Showing (at all)

Tags: animation, 2d

I've decided to learn Grease Pencil for 2D animation in Blender, however the option for Grease Pencil isn't showing up at all.

I've downloaded 2.79 for Mac (as screen capped) so I don't know what I'm doing wrong, is there something else I need to download to get it to work?

Any help is greatly appreciated, Thanks!

Gemma

[image] 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are looking in the wrong place.

in 2.79 the controls for grease pencil are on the tools and properties window.

[image]